# how to get a value from textbox and pass it from actionlink to controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, html.textboxfor

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC application and i need to pass TextBox value from view to controller this TextBox is in table and i need get the input value.

```
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
      <tr class="odd gradeX">
        <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Product.ProductName)
      </td>
      <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User.FullName)
      </td>
      <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Product.Reference)
      </td>
      <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.QuantityWanted, new { style = "width:60%", type = "number", min = "0", step = "1", max = item.Quantity })
      @Html.ActionLink("Add", "Add", new { idProduct = item.ProductID, idUser = item.UserID, quantityWanted= item.QuantityWanted })
      </td>

      </tr>
    }
```

I used javascript and jquery but i didn't get anything and quantityWanted always returns null or 0 value.

Comment: This won't work, this code will render once only, once rendered, it won't change, and that will happen before you even see the text box, for your case, I advice using ajax call to submit this.

Comment: can you explain code? Your model is Enumerable? what exactly you want? jquery or just link?

Comment: yes my model is Enumerable and i want to pass txtbox value to controller via link

Comment: you can't send textbox value ,because when textbox value change,link wont change.you have to send value via jquery.

Comment: how ? can you give an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want code like this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
  <tr class="odd gradeX">
    <td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Product.ProductName)
  </td>
  <td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User.FullName)
  </td>
  <td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Product.Reference)
  </td>
  <td>

    <input type="number" id="Quantity@item.ProductID" data-idUser = "@item.UserID" style="width:60%" min="0" step="1" max="@item.Quantity"/>
    <button click="AddItem(@item.ProductID)">Click to add</button>

  </td>

  </tr>
}

<script>
function AddItem(id){
var quantity = $('Quantity' + id).val();
    window.location = "/Add/Add?idProduct" + id + "&idUser=" + $('Quantity' + id).data("idUser") + "&quantityWanted=" + quantity;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. it worked for me. the idea was to give a different ID for every input so we can retrieve his value